# TypeScript - 'Element' is not assignable to HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I am working with TypeScript and React. In my component, which is a dialog window, I want to store the trigger element, such as a button as a property. When the component unmounts, I want to return focus to that element. However, I am receiving an error from TSLint that I am not sure how to resolve.

```
class Dialog extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  ...
  focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened: HTMLInputElement;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened = document.activeElement;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I am receiving the error on the line where I am assigning the property value:

```
[ts] Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
  Property 'accept' is missing in type 'Element'.
```

However, if I change the type of the property to `Element` or even `HTMLInputElement` I receive an error in `componentWillUnmount()`

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    ...
    this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened.focus();
}
```

This error is in regards to Element type not having the `focus()` method.

**Question**

Is there a way to tell TypeScript that `document.activeElement` should be an input type? Something like

`this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened = <HTMLInputElement>document.activeElement;`

Or is there a better way around this so declare the type that supports both `document.activeElement` and `.focus()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React but in Angular, you have the `nativeElement` property. Don't you have it after ` activeElement` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs of [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement):

> Often this will return an `<input>` or `<textarea>` object, if it has the text selection at the time.  If so, you can get more detail by using the element's selectionStart and selectionEnd properties.  Other times the focused element might be a `<select>` element (menu) or an `<input>` element, of type button, checkbox or radio.

That is, `document.activeElement` is not necessarily an instance of `HTMLInputElement` (it can also be a `HTMLSelectElement`, etc.).

If you are indeed only looking for a `HTMLInputElement`, you can use a simple `instanceof` type-guard, which is recognized by TypeScript:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened = document.activeElement;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Additionally, you can detect if the element is *focusable*, e.g. by defining your own type-guard:

```
interface IFocusableElement {
    focus(): void;
}

function isFocusable(element: any): element is IFocusableElement {
    return (typeof element.focus === "function");
}
```

And then use `IFocusableElement` as the type of `this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened` and your own type guard:

```
focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened: IFocusableElement;

componentDidMount() {
    if (document.activeElement && isFocusable(document.activeElement)) {
        this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened = document.activeElement;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you also need the original API offered by `Element`, you can just use an intersection type:

```
focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened: IFocusableElement & Element;
```

Comment: Since it seems HTMLInputElement only returns <input type='button'> would it be advised to add HTMLButtonElement as well to the possible type and type guard to support <button> elements?

Comment: This solution has some elegant parts but is not complete since the `componentWillUnmount()` can call `this.focusedElementBeforeDialogOpened.focus();` on `undefined` when `document.activeElement` has no `focus` method!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the definitions in `lib.es6.d.ts` are a bit inconsistent, unless it's the W3C specifications that are a bit confusing:

```js
interface Document extends [...] {
    /**
     * Gets the object that has the focus when the parent document has focus.
     */
    readonly activeElement: Element;
    [...]
    focus(): void;
    [...]
}

interface HTMLElement extends Element {
    [...]
    focus(): void;
    [...]
}
```

So, the 2 only kind of objects that we can focus manually are `Document` and `HtmlElement`, but any `Element` can be focused!

If you only need to give back the focus, you can do something like:

```js
class Dialog extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    private resetFocus = () => {};

    componentDidMount() {
        const elementToFocus = document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement
            ? document.activeElement
            : document;
        this.resetFocus = () => elementToFocus.focus();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.resetFocus();
    }
}
```

or

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const activeElement = document.activeElement as any;
    if (typeof activeElement.focus === 'function') {
        this.resetFocus = () => activeElement.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for some of the documentation there. Giving back the focus isn't my concern. I am trying to find how to avoid using type 'any'.

Comment: I've just edited the code to remove unecessary `any`. It may better fit your  needs ^^